# How to limit concurrent connection per user and same routing key in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

I would like to know if there is a way in RabbitMQ to restrict from the server side to the users to be able to connect with the same credentials and routing key only once at a time.

I mean: Limit concurrent connection per user and same routing key,No shared connections.

If the user is connected with X credentials and listening on route y.z and try to connect in another machine with same info, then the server should deny the connection.

And i would like to apply this restrictions from the server, to avoid hacks in the client side.

Is there a way to do this or something similar?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

There are no out of the box solutions for that, AFIK.

You can create [exclusive queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.declare.exclusive) named something like `queue_name.user_name`, bind it as you wish to desired exchanges and then consume from this queue. It will guaranties that one and only one consumer at a time can be connected to it.

Comment: Agree- AMQP does not support this natively. To enforce rigidity, you would need a message-passing layer (possibly a web service) between your RabbitMQ and your clients.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, i will try it, i knew about exclusivity, but that can be changed in the client side, i suppose there is nothing in the AMQP protocolo,but was hoping some implementation in the rabbitmq server, also, using a layer as a web service is a possible solution too, but once again the code can be changed in the client side to jump this, so, probably something in the server that check connected users and disconnect the repeated one ?

Comment: Nope, maybe there are some plugin for that but I don't know any of a kind. Ask this question on RabbitMQ irc or mailing list, maybe someone there will have answer for your q. Btw, you can write it, RabbitMQ written in erlang and it's code licensed under opensource license, so it won't be hard.